# How to save data in a salesforce account using react-native?

Tags: react-native, salesforce, salesforce-mobile-sdk

We are building an Application and we need to store some data to the user's Salesforce account. I looked into some solutions where people are using Apex but I am unable to understand how to use them with React Native.

Please give me some good documentations to refer of How can I save my data from my React Native App to my Salesforce Account.

I tried to look into Apex and visualforce but not understanding how to use it with React Native.

Comment: are they providing API's for that?

Comment: You'll have to call a REST API with an access token. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_authentication.htm

Comment: None of the API's are provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For react Native you will have to call REST API exposed by salesforce. You will need to create a connected app and get the security key and client id. Use them to authenticate and get a access_token. Once you have that token, use it to make a POST call to /services/data/v45.0/sobjects/Account using the account id. Send a JSON payload to add your data.

Example of a GET call is :

/services/data/v45.0/sobjects/Account/0013600000udFs8AAE

Hope this helps!

Comment: Minor correction: to "save" data, it cannot be a GET.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But is there any API which directly calls the internal field of (Adding a new Note) in salesforce ?

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/104408/how-can-i-create-an-account-note-or-contact-note-via-api-that-is-visible-in-sale . In general, questions that are very Salesforce-specific should be posted to [SFSE] (https://salesforce.stackexchange.com)